# Java set color to jtable after button press

Tags: java

I have a jtable that has a delete button, when i select a row and clicked to delete button I want the set that row to green color.

However when i click away, the row color did not remain there and which every row I selected become green instead of default blue

```
public class table extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    DefaultTableModel model;
    private boolean btnClicked = false;

    public table() {
        initComponents();
        model = (DefaultTableModel) tbltable.getModel();

    }

    public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);


            if (isSelected) {

                cell.setBackground(getBackground());                
                String type = (String) String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 3));
                if (("deleted").equals(type)) {
                    cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }

            }
            return cell;

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        txtCol1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtCol2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtCol3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tbltable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        btnEdit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnDelete = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        txtCol1.setText("jTextField1");

        txtCol2.setText("jTextField2");

        txtCol3.setText("jTextField3");

        btnAdd.setText("Add");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tbltable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.String.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        tbltable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                tbltableMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tbltable);

        btnEdit.setText("edit");
        btnEdit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnEditActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnDelete.setText("delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnDeleteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(92, 92, 92)
                        .addComponent(txtCol1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(txtCol2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(txtCol3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 452, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btnAdd)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnEdit)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnDelete)))))
                .addContainerGap(283, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtCol1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(txtCol2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(txtCol3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnAdd)
                    .addComponent(btnEdit)
                    .addComponent(btnDelete))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 273, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(95, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

        String chkcol = "notdeleted";
        model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{txtCol1.getText(), txtCol2.getText(), txtCol3.getText(), chkcol});
    }                                      

    private void tbltableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        txtCol1.setText(String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 0)));
        txtCol2.setText(String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 1)));
        txtCol3.setText(String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 2)));
        int rowIndex = tbltable.getSelectedRow();
        System.out.println("rowIndex " + rowIndex);
    }                                     

    private void btnEditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        model.setValueAt(txtCol1.getText(), tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 0);
        model.setValueAt(txtCol2.getText(), tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 1);
        model.setValueAt(txtCol3.getText(), tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 2);
    }                                       
    TableColumn tcol;
    private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        model.setValueAt("deleted", tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 3);

        if (String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(tbltable.getSelectedRow(), 3)).equals("deleted")) {
            tcol = tbltable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
            tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());

            tcol = tbltable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
            tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());

            tcol = tbltable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
            tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());

            tcol = tbltable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
            tcol.setCellRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer());
        }


    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(table.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(table.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(table.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(table.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new table().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDelete;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEdit;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable tbltable;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCol1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCol2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtCol3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Below is the image that showcase my issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you keep a column in the TableModel that contains a Boolean value to indicate if the row is deleted or not. This column should not display in the JTable. You can remove it from the JTable view by using:

```
table.removeColumn( table.getColumn(...) );
```

Then you can check out [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which shows how you can render a row based on a value in the row.

Don't forget when you test the Boolean value for the row you need to use:

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(...);
```

because the table does not have access to the value since it is not displayed in the table.

Comment: ok let me , rewrite my table and post again if i face any issue again. thanks

Comment: i have added another column with some flag to indicate row delete. But the result of coloring the row is not as expected...after delete button is press anything select automatically turn green now

Comment: @forttest, well you didn't listen to the suggestion so I can't really help. As soon as you change the renderer for the columns all rows will share the same renderer. I suggested you store Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.False in the TableModel for the column. I then suggested you override the `prepareRenderer(...)` as demonstrated in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking a look at [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) and [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

The important thing here is that each cell in your table is using the same `TableCellRenderer` to be rendered with (at least in your case, it's more complicated if you have different data types), this means that the `TableCellRenderer` is stateless and it's context is passed to it via the parameters to the `getTableCellRendererComponent`

You will need to update the state of each cell each time `getTableCellRendererComponent` is called

You will need to some way to determine if the row is deleted or not and render the state specifically if it is.